# How to apply sas like formatting in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create the cross tabulation frequency table in python as in 2 way frequency in SAS.

In SAS,they have used PROC FORMAT to display few contents in the output as per requirement.

How do I achieve this in python?For example,one of the datasets has got a column as age_group with categories 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 and 8.

But in print output,I want to display them as '0-23','24-27','48-59','60-71','72-79','80-87','88-99' and '100+' respectively with their frequencies.
(Note: I do not want to change the original data).

I have checked few formatting options,but most of them seem to be for floating points etc.How should I do this customized formatting for print?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cat.rename_categories()` method to rename the categories. If you want to work with the original levels consequently, you can use `cat.codes` to get the underlying integers. Here's a reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age_group':["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]}, 
                  dtype="category")

# Rename categories
df.age_group = df.age_group.cat.rename_categories([ '0-23','24-27','48-59',
                                                   '60-71','72-79','80-87','88-99'])
# Test
> df
    age_group
0   0-23
1   24-27
2   48-59
3   60-71
4   72-79
5   80-87
6   88-99

# Underlying integers
> df.age_group.cat.codes
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
dtype: int8
```

Alternatively, if your column is not categorical, you could use a dictionary in combination with `.replace()` to print the associated values.

```
# Create data and dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame({'age_group':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
d = {1:'0-23',2:'24-27',3:'48-59',4:'60-71',5:'72-79',6:'80-87',7:'88-99'}

# Print matching values
df.replace({"age_group": d})
    age_group
0   0-23
1   24-27
2   48-59
3   60-71
4   72-79
5   80-87
6   88-99
```

Comment: @mtoto....if they are not in categories,do i need to convert them and apply that above procedure?is there any other method without renaming categories  like apply format to column just for print sake because when I want to see the df,it should still have codes and when I am printing it that format should be applied.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

# DataFrame containing the SAS format #
df_format = pd.DataFrame({'grp_code':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'grp_decode':['0-23','24-27','48-59','60-71','72-79','80-87','88-99']})

df_format = df_format.set_index('grp_code')

# DataFrame containing the source data #
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'age_grp_code':[1,2,3,4,5,6,2,1,7,3,2]})

# Apply the format decode in a new column #
df_data['age_grp_decode'] = df_data.replace({'age_grp_code': df_format['grp_decode']})
print(df_data)
```